# Triangles with proportional sides

Tags: geometry

If in $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle DEF$ we have angle $\angle A = \angle D$ and $AB:DE=BC:EF$ then prove that $\angle C = \angle F$ or $\angle C+ \angle F =180^\circ$.

Comment: Welcome to M.SE , Aman Verma . It will be better if you add you attempt and where you got struck.

Comment: Hint: Use Thales' theorem.

Comment: How can I use Thales theorem, please can you elaborate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1) The Law of Sines:
$$\frac{BC}{\sin A}=\frac{AB}{\sin C} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
\frac{EF}{\sin D}=\frac{DE}{\sin F}.$$
2) Divide.

Answer (score 2):

In △ABC assume *AB = c, BC = a, CA = b*.

Similarly, In △DEF assume *DE = f, EF = d, FD = e*.

Given, *∠A=∠D*

and *$$\frac{c}{f} = \frac{a}{d}$$*

=> *$$c = \frac{a.f}{d} \tag{1}$$*

In △ABC applying sine rule,
*$$\frac{sin A}{a} = \frac{sin C}{c}\tag{2}$$*

=> from equation (1) and (2) we get,
*$$\frac{sin A}{a} = \frac{sin C}{\frac{a.f}{d}}$$*
or, *$$\frac{sin A}{sin C} = \frac{d}{f}\tag{3}$$*

Similarly, In △DEF applying sine rule,
*$$\frac{sin D}{d} = \frac{sin F}{f}$$*
or, *$$\frac{d}{f} = \frac{sin D}{sin F}\tag{4}$$*

On equating equations (3) and (4) we get,
*$$\frac{sin A}{sin C} = \frac{sin D}{sin F}$$*
Since, *∠A=∠D*,
=>*$$sin C = sin F $$*
From general solution of sine equation we have,
*$$C = nπ + (-1)^n.F$$*
for *n = 0*,
*$$C = F$$* or ***$$∠C=∠F$$***
for *n = 1*
*$$C = π - F$$*
or, *$$C + F = π$$*
or, ***$$∠C + ∠F = π$$***